# entries.onSaveEntry does not fire from frontend

Tags: plugin-development, entries, events

I created my own `actionEntrySave` for my frontend form. and I'm using the
 `$entryService->saveEntry($entry);` method to store my entries into the database.
The problem is this does not fire

```
craft()->on('entries.onSaveEntry', function(Event $event) {
    die(var_dump("fired"));
});
```

When I save/edit the same entry in the backend or create a new one I see an empty page with "fired" there.. (just for testing) and I can manipulate the entry the way I want without any problems. If I do the same in the frontend (saving/editing an entry) the event does not trigger but the entry saves. Can someone explain why?

Thank you very much

edit: I already tried onBeforeSaveEntry with the same result

**Edit 2 Solved**

I solved it now.. my error was I did this

```
$entryService = new EntriesService();
$dbInsert = $entryService->saveEntry($entry);
```

But it has to look like

```
$entryService = craft()->entries;
$dbInsert = $entryService->saveEntry($entry);
```

I thought all services were singletons. My mistake

Answer (score 2):

Where is your "craft()-on()" code located?

Per the documentation, the best place is in your primary plugin file in a method named "init()".

https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events#listening-for-events

For example, here's mine:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    // event triggers
    craft()->on('charge.onValidate', array($this, '_validateRegistrationForm'));
    craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', array($this, '_processEditPricelistLocationForm'));
    craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', array($this, '_processEditGuestUsersForm'));
    craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', array($this, '_processGuestUserAccessForm'));
    craft()->on('entries.onBeforeSaveEntry', array($this, '_processEditGuestRemoveUsersForm'));
}
```

and here's just showing that I do in fact handle the Event $event in the method:

```
/**
 * Charge onValidate
 *
 * @param Event $event
 */
public function _validateRegistrationForm(Event $event)
{
    // do stuff
}
```