# Programmatically create new entry with saveElement

Tags: entrymodel

I am currently trying to save a new entry with `craft()->elements->saveElement()`, as I want to avoid triggering the `onBeforeSave` and `onAfterSave` events.

When I run my script, it returns a successful entry id, but there is no entry in the admin.

Here is my code:

```
$entry = new EntryModel();
$entry->sectionId = $sectionId;
$entry->typeId = $entryTypeId;
$entry->enabled = true;
$entry->authorId = 1;

$success = craft()->elements->saveElement($entry, false);

if ($success) {
    echo $entry->id;
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but check out Craft's own `craft/app/controllers/EntriesController->saveEntry()` to see how an EntryModel is created and populated and passed off to the ElementsService.

Comment: Thanks! I've done a little digging there but haven't quite figured out what might be missing. I'll keep digging.

Comment: @BradBell I ended up copying the `saveEntry` method from the `EntriesService` and ripping out anything event related.

Additionally, I think it'd be amazing if there were a way to call saveEntry and disable any events, although I don't know if that would ever be possible.

Comment: You can do that by simply create a new instance of the entries service I noticed that by mistake https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19334/entries-onsaveentry-does-not-fire-from-frontend

Answer (score 3):

In Craft's v3 API documentation they give an example:

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-elements.html#method-saveelement

```
$entry = new Entry();
$entry->sectionId = 10;
$entry->typeId = 1;
$entry->authorId = 5;
$entry->enabled = true;
$entry->title = "Hello World!";
$entry->setFieldValues([
    'body' => "<p>I can’t believe I literally just called this “Hello World!”.</p>",
]);
$success = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
if (!$success) {
    Craft::error('Couldn’t save the entry "'.$entry->title.'"', __METHOD__);
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, this is not the question I was asking above if you will notice. I was asking how to prevent re-triggering the onBeforeSave and onAfterSave if I create entries programmatically.